# How to Find the number of tangents to the curve y=$f\left(x\right)$ parallel to line $x+y=0$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> **Question** For $x$$>0,$ let
>
> $f\left(x\right)=\int_{1}^{x}\left(\sqrt{\log t}-\frac{1}{2}\log\sqrt{t}\right)dt$
>
> The number of tangents to the curve y=$f\left(x\right)$parallel to
>   line x+y=0 is _________________
>
> [image]

**MY approach** $x+y=0\Longrightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}=-1$

$f\left(x\right)=\int_{1}^{x}\left(\sqrt{\log t}-\frac{1}{2}\log\sqrt{t}\right)dt$$\Longrightarrow f'\left(x\right)=$$\sqrt{\log x}-\frac{1}{2}\log\sqrt{x}$

I know that parallel lines have same slope,but it would not give me
number of tangents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Finding the number of tangents of $f(x)$ parallel to line $y=-x$ is equivalent to finding the number of roots of the equation $f'(x)=-1$.

Comment: I Got it thanks

Answer (score 1):

In each point where you will have $f'(x)=-1$ you will have such a tangent : 
\begin{align*}
&-1=\sqrt{logx}-\frac{1}{2}log\sqrt{x} 
\end{align*}
Since $f'$ seems to be a positive function (after a quick study of it), the answer must be $0$...

Comment: I think you meant $f'(x)=-1$... Also, the equivalence is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, edited now :)